# Как сделать эту паузу между отправкой сообщений ботом?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я создаю своего ВК бота и у меня возникла проблема:
Я сделал так, что когда пользователь пишет "начать историю", то бот начинает отправлять ему огромный текст, но по предложениям с паузой в несколько секунд. Как сделать эту паузу между отправкой сообщений ботом?

```
elif body.lower() == "начать историю":
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "12 января 2009 года.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Холодный зимний вечер.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Вы сидели в своей захолустной однушке и страдали, откровенно говоря, хренью.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
```

Comment: Вызвать sleep между отправками бота

Comment: каким образом вызвать sleep?

Comment: Импортировать `time` и у него вызывать функцию `sleep`. Но это если у вас асинхронный бот, тогда нужен другой `sleep`

Comment: не получается через обычный sleep. print ("hello") и

Comment: как сделать через другой sleep ?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код. Не мне охото играть в экстрасенсов :)

Comment: каким образом можно добавить код?

Comment: добавлю его в ответы :)

Comment: смотри ниже короче)

Comment: чекай ниже, ответил

Comment: мне нужно между вк методами вставить паузу

Comment: Ниже вопроса есть кнопка `править`, через нее и добавляйте код. Не забывайте форматировать его. Ваш код из ответа перенес в вопрос. Еще, свои комментарии тоже можно править, поэтому не флудите, а дополняйте комментарий что есть (пока 5 минут не пройдет с его создания, его можно редактировать)

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы делать паузу между отправками сообщений, можно использовать функцию [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```py
import time

print('Hello ...')
time.sleep(10)
print('... World!')
```

В вашем случае:

```py
vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "12 января 2009 года.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
time.sleep(10)
vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Холодный зимний вечер.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
time.sleep(10)
vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Вы сидели в своей захолустной однушке и страдали, откровенно говоря, хренью.", "random_id": int(time.time())})
```

Но будьте аккуратны, потому что данная функция заблокирует все ваше приложение на 10 секунд. То есть второй пользователь параллельно не получит ответ от бота вовремя, а лишь спустя 10 секунд. Вам бы в сторону [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) и асинхронных библиотек для работы с VK смотреть тогда.

Для асинхронного кода функция `sleep` будет несколько иначе:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('... World!')

# Python 3.7+
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Error: 'await' outside function

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
import time

time.sleep(10)
```